# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>' from 'Class'

Tags: warnings, ios5

I have a "**Utility**" class that implements the **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** protocol.

This is my **Utility.h**

```
@interface Utility : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
}
```

And this is its counterpart **Utility.m**

```
@implementation Utility

static AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

+ (void)playAudioFromFileName:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)type withPlayerFinishCallback:(SEL)callback onObject:(id)callbackObject
{
    ... 
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [self getResourceURLForName:name ofType:type] error: nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self; // this is the line that causes the Warning
    ...
}
```

My iOS application works well, however after migrating to iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2 the compiler started throwing this warning, located at the `audioPlayer.delegate = self;` line:

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to id <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> from 'Class'
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've declared your method as a class method, and you're trying to use the Class object as the delegate.  But you can't add protocols to Class objects.

You need to change `playAudioFromFileName:...` to an instance method and create an instance of `Utility` to use as the delegate.  Maybe you want to have a single instance of `Utility` shared by all callers.  This is the Singleton pattern, and it's pretty common in Cocoa.  You do something like this:

### Utility.h

```
@interface Utility : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
+ (Utility *)sharedUtility;
@end
```

### Utility.m

```
@implementation Utility

+ (Utility *)sharedUtility
{
    static Utility *theUtility;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!theUtility)
            theUtility = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return theUtility;
}

- (void)playAudioFromFileName:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)type withPlayerFinishCallback:(SEL)callback onObject:(id)callbackObject
{
    ... 
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [self getResourceURLForName:name ofType:type] error: nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    ...
}

@end
```

### Usage

```
[[Utility sharedUtility] playAudioFromFileName:@"quack" ofType:"mp3" withPlayerFinishCallback:@selector(doneQuacking:) onObject:duck];
```

Comment: It's funny though that it actually always worked and still works to use self as a audioplayer delegate (delegate methods of the class will be called without problem), bet lots of code out there in the appstore is still running like that. Just there is a warning.

Answer (score 7):

When you don't need an instance of a Class, just manually get ride of the warning:

```
audioPlayer.delegate = (id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)self;
```

On the other hand, please note that if you need a Delegate, it means you should have an instance of a Class as a good coding practice instead of a static Class. It can be made a [singleton](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) easily:

```
static id _sharedInstance = nil;
+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t p;
    dispatch_once(&p, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: I used this to get rid of the warning and the delegate still works.

Comment: Yes @user523234, that's the goal. :)