# How to solve the warning: Sending 'ViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

The following code gave a warning of `Sending 'ViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>'` (it is the third line in the following code):

```
NSURL *sound0URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"0" ofType:@"aiff"]];

audioPlayer0 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sound0URL error:nil];

[audioPlayer0 setDelegate: self];   // <---   this line causes the warning
[audioPlayer0 prepareToPlay];

audioPlayer0.currentTime = 0;
[audioPlayer0 play];
```

How can it be fixed?  I have this code in the `ViewController`'s instance method of `viewDidLoad`.  There was another question similar but that was a class method: [Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>' from 'Class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940477/incompatible-pointer-types-assigning-to-idavaudioplayerdelegate-from-class)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Conform to the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol in your header file and the warning will go away.  By not declaring that a class conforms to a given protocol, the compiler cannot guarantee (well, at least warn) about your failure to implement the methods required of it.  The following code is a corrected version that will suppress the warning.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
@end
```

Answer (score 34):

Interestingly that didn't do it for me. I have the delegate defined in header file - working with **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** in a **UITableViewController**. Since setDelegate method expected an id, I set delegate as follows instead:

```
[myImagePicker setDelegate: (id)self];
```

But I would like to know what's happening here ? Since this is not normally showing itself in other delegate examples in other areas of code. Could anyone elucidate on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Same here - my .h file has the delegate defined but the warning persists

Comment: Maybe you have your controller defined as UIViewController or UITableViewController (for example) and your myImagePicker is a UINavigationController... that could cause the warning.

Comment: [myImagePicker setDelegate: (id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)self];

Comment: Back four years later .... the header file did have '@interface MyClassName: NSObject <SomeDelegate>', but it did not have '#import "SomeDelegate.h"'.

Answer (score 5):

Your self (your class) doesnt have the

```
@interface MyClassName: NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

in the header file.

Answer (score 4):

This is a warning telling you that you are missed to define your delegate in .h file

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject <YourDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you adding delegate inside UIComponent braces

Eg: 
@interface DemoView : UIView < UITableViewDelegate>

rather than delegate property you are creating.

@property(retain)id < UITableViewDelegate> demoDelegate